# Finder dragging hang / stuck

Tags: macos, finder

*Sometimes* when dragging files from folder to another, or moving a folder, the items being dragged are stuck in the dragging mode and it hangs. I can see Finder use 30-35% CPU at that moment.

Anyone facing the same problem?

I'm on 10.7.2 also using FlexiGlass for Window moving/resizing.

Comment: I have had this same problem on 10.7.3 on both my iMac and Macbookpro. I will try to see if sleeping makes a difference. How ever due to my lack of patience I wen back to running 10.6.8+. There it works okay 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would say restart you Mac if you have not done so in a while.
2. Try [repairing the disk and repairing permissions in Disk Utility](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mchlp1718.html).
3. Next try deleting your Finder preferences. Your looking for a file called:

   com.apple.finder.plist

   Note you might want to back this file up before deleting, if you spent a lot of time configuring Finder view, etc and this turns out to not fix the issue.

   This file will be located at /Users/YourUSERname/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
4. Restart and see if it happens anymore.
5. Try installing [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) and use it to reset Finder related settings.
6. Try removing FlexiGlass if you suspect that is causing issues.
7. Try logging in as another user and see if the issues comes up while logged in as another user.
8. If all else fails, back up your stuff and reinstall Lion.

Comment: i was experiencing this same issue on 10.7.3, your suggestion for deleting the finder prefs with the addition of relaunching finder and then emptying the trash seemed to do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this happens again, try restarting the Finder service by the following commands:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.Finder
launchctl start com.apple.Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

**TEMPORARY FIX**

Ok, this is very a very odd & temporary fix but apparently put your mac to sleep and then wake it if you are having this finder hanging issue and it should resolve it. I thought I resolved the issue by deleting finder prefs but it came back a week later. Apparently there is a bug in lion that many other users are experiencing in 10.7.2 and 10.7.3. After waking from sleep I have noticed the issue is always gone, however it will not last across a reboot. Hopefully this is affecting enough users that it makes its way to apple engineers so they can correct it for the next point update.